# Contact Form 7 Not Submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Not sure what is causing this problem, if you click Request A Quote from [this](http://gbn-primo.co.uk/product/p1724a-armchair) page you'll notice that even if you fill out the form, it doesn't submit! I'm pretty sure this may be down to a JS conflict but thought I'd post it up here in case I'm way off....

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: What're you talking about? The link above is a site I'm working on and need help with.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a regular link `a` to submit the form, do you manage the click event with JS in any way?

Since you're using the HTML `form`, why not simply use a button :

```
<button class="button-submit">Request a quote</button>
```

Or, add this to your link : `onclick="form.submit();".`

Like so :

```
<a href="#" class="button-submit" onclick="form.submit();">Request a quote</a>
```

Comment: Cheers will give it a go! It's probably down to the fact it's a wordpress plugin that's generating the form, I know that this plugin uses js to handle events which is what leads me to believe it must be a js conflict...

Comment: It could be, since it's a regular link and that they don't submit forms by default, I suppose that somewhere in the JS code is the handler for the link click event that then submits the form. If you  are able to edit the HTML, simply replace the `a` with a `button` and it will submit the form on click by default. ;)

Comment: No such luck =/ Looks like I'm gonna have to get up to elbows in minified js -.-

Comment: Ok tell a lie, turns out the guy who wrote this decided that this form didn't need to be submitted or validated lol.